# How to copy/move Mosaic Dataset to another location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, erdas-imagine, mosaic

On my previous question on Mosaic Dataset vs. ERDAS 2011 [Is ERDAS 2011 or ArcGIS 10.1 best to use when mosaicking 100's of ECW image files?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79520/is-erdas-2011-or-arcgis-10-1-best-to-use-when-mosaicking-100s-of-ecw-image-file), I did research for a bit was wondering what happens if you use the Mosiac Dataset and decided to copy and move to another computer. It would display a black and white checkerboard.

Do I need to copy the original ECW files along with the Mosaic Dataset geodatabase for it to make it work or display it ?

When I load the moasic dataset to ArcMap, the only way to see the imagery is to zoom in ?
Is there a specific scale that can I see one set of imagery ?

[image: Mosaic Dataset Sample]

Any suggestion ?

One problem with ERDAS is that I can do it but the image is actually came from ArcSDE we recieved from BLM and when I review it and it has the tiles which doesn't show overlaid each other. This is the reason why I choose Mosaic Dataet.

Answer (score 1):

When you move any rasters referenced by a mosaic dataset, including overviews, you must [repair the paths](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009t0000005n000000) locating these rasters.

Answer (score -2):

When you move rasters referenced by a mosaic dataset to another machine, the tool "repair the paths" sometimes does not work. Also there are some problems when you publish this data (by ArcGis Server). Moreover, sometimes you need copy your data (source rasters) into the location with the same name.

I "fixed" this problems when I generated RasterDataset from MosaicDataset. So I can copy data to any computer and also publish it. In my situation there are no big difference in speed display (raster or mosaic).